# Read a file and cut each line based on multiple criteria

Tags: java, python, perl, bash

I found it tough to come up with a proper title for this question. So, if it is misleading, I would appreciate if you can help improve it.

I have extracted the value of the attributes of an xml file and now I have output as mentioned in an example line below:

```
category:buffer overflow  analyzer:data flow analyzer:buffer
```

I need to split this as

```
category:buffer overflow
analyzer:data flow
analyzer:buffer
```

I am not sure how to get this done using Java, Perl or Python.

Till now all I have is a simple Perl script that splits this on ":".

All suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Reworking your extractor to produce the desired output sounds much more viable.

Comment: I would, if I could. This is a file that I have received as part of a zip file containing some metrics data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this **sed** one-liner works here:

```
sed -r 's/ ([^ ]+:)/\n\1/g' input
```

test:

```
kent$  echo "category:buffer overflow  analyzer:data flow analyzer:buffer" |sed -r 's/ ([^ ]+:)/\n\1/g'                                                                     
category:buffer overflow 
analyzer:data flow
analyzer:buffer
```

this **java** line works here too:

```
System.out.println("category:buffer overflow  analyzer:data flow analyzer:buffer".replaceAll("\\s([^\\s]+:)", "\n$1"));
```

yet another **python** line:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s = 'category:buffer overflow  analyzer:data flow analyzer:buffer'                                                                                                 

In [3]: print re.sub(r"\s(?=[^\s]*:)",'\n',s)
category:buffer overflow 
analyzer:data flow
analyzer:buffer
```

Answer (score 5):

A suitable regular expression will work. Here's an implementation with Python's `re` module:

```
import re

s = 'category:buffer overflow  analyzer:data flow analyzer:buffer'

print(re.findall(r"(\w+:[\w ]+)(?: |$)", s))
#prints ['category:buffer overflow ', 'analyzer:data flow', 'analyzer:buffer']
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java this would look like this:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Extractor {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern
                .compile("(\\w+:[\\w ]+)(?: |$)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern
                .matcher("category:buffer overflow  analyzer:data flow analyzer:buffer");
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In perl:

```
$s = "category:buffer overflow  analyzer:data flow analyzer:buffer";
$s .= " "; 
@keyz = split(/:[A-Za-z\d\s]*\s/, $s);
print "@keyz\n";
@params = split(/[A-Za-z\d]*:/, $s);
print "@params\n";
```

produces array @keyz = ("category", "analyzer", "analyzer") and array @params=("buffer overflow", "data flow", "buffer")